# Photoshop cs6 ubuntu layerchanges won't update

Tags: ubuntu

I've just got Photoshop Cs6 working on Ubuntu making use of Playonlinux.
Took me some time since I just transfered from Windows to Ubunto (which I'm untill now very happy about).
Now every time when I perform an action like hide a layer, making use of color overlay the action doesn't execute within the design.

Now by accident I found out that when I minimize or maximize the screen, the action gets executed. Since it very unpractical to minimize or maximize after each action it would be great to fix this issue.

I've tried to restart playbylinux but it doesn't make a difference. I'm making use of Ubuntu 17.04

Anybody can help me with a solution?

Thanks in advance!

**-Edit-**

Found out it probably is a problem with the OPENGL, but haven't been able to find a working fix. Also I've updated Wine but same result.